# WSO2 Api Manager 1.7 : Unable to regenerate access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using the latest version 1.7 and downloaded the binary from WSO2 API Manager site on 11th June. 
As per a Jira post : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2290
This issue was resolved as of 14th May,2014, but I am still getting it..Please help

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-06-13 15:14:33,990] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error in getting new accessToken {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in getting new accessToken
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.renewAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.regenerateApplicationAccessKey(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_refreshToken(APIStoreHostObject.java:3219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2._c_anonymous_3(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:61)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_10(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:35)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:206)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-06-13 15:14:33,996] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in getting new accessToken {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running on a port other than the default port you would need to make **changes to port references** in multiple files located under

- **/repository/conf**
- **/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api**

Answer (score 1):

You are having issue with verifying host name. If you are running API Manager with port offset 2 go to

*[APIM_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api*

- *AuthorizeAPI*.xml in here The default address endpoint config is `address uri="https://localhost:9443//oauth2/authorize"`
  if the port offset is 2 change this config as address `uri="https://localhost:9445/oauth2/authorize"`
- Change congig in *RevokeAPI*.xml as
  address `uri="https://localhost:9445/oauth2/revoke"`
- Change congig in *TokenAPI*.xml files in as
  `address uri="https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token"`

Also change the  in api-manager.xml [AM/repository/conf] to match with port offset value.
`<RevokeAPIURL>https://localhost:8245/revoke</RevokeAPIURL>`